# Can't change fav icon

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 project. I tried to change the default favicon. I simply deleted the old one and added in my one. The name is still the same, favicon.ico.

However when I run the project it still shows me this old one:

[image]

I tried adding a line of CSS to the shared layout file or an individual html file, but both times it did not work. This is the line of CSS that I used, the favicon is saved on the same level as the content, controller, ... folders.

```
<link rel="icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do the browser's dev tools show the correct icon being requested? Does forcing a full refresh (control-F5 on mo9st browsers) help (browser is caching the file)?

Comment: I clean the project, rebuild it, then clear the cache and refresh. Nothing helps at all. I'll look at it with Dev tools now, any guidance where to look for that specifically though?

Comment: Yes it shows me this <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> which should be right

Comment: Look at the network tab to see requests: for example.sf the tilde being handled correctly?

Comment: What directory is your favicon in. Have you tried the absolute URL "hhtp://MySite.com/favicon.ico", Also check permissions in the file.

Comment: The problem is solved-ish. The favicon loads on the test server, just not in my local environment.